# Spring Boot Testing - No Qualifying Bean Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

While attempting some tests using the Spring Boot framework, I am running into an issue with finding a Bean that the test unit depends on.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'authServerApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'passwordEncoder'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My test class:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@SpringBootTest

public class UserDetailsTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

//    @MockBean
//    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        OAuthUser user = null;
        this.entityManager.persist(new OAuthUser("Kelly", "Marchewa", "kmarchewa", "password"));
        user = userRepo.findByUserName("kmarchewa");
        System.out.println(user.getPassword());
        assertThat(user.getUserName()).isEqualTo("kmarchewa");


    }

}
```

If I uncomment the @MockBean portion, the code will compile fine. However, I want to test the repository on its ability to encode and decode passwords too. To my understanding of [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html), the @SpringBootTest annotation should be able to automatically "pick-up" the @Configuration classes. I have a main @SpringBootApplication:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AuthServerApplication {

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(AuthServerApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
public CommandLineRunner demo(UserRepository repository) {
    return(args) -> {
        OAuthUser user = new OAuthUser();


        user.setFirstName("Kelly");
        user.setLastName("Marchewa");
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode("Admin"));
        user.setUserName("Admin");

    // repository.save(user);
    };
}
}
```

This Spring Boot Application depends on three other @Configuration classes: AppConfig, SecurityConfig, and AuthServerConfig. For this issue, the SecurityConfig and AppConfig classes are relevant (they include references to  the PasswordEncoder bean).

AppConfig (partial)

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

        @Value("${spring.datasource.url}")
        private String datasourceUrl;

        @Value("${spring.datasource.driverClassName}")
        private String dbDriverClassName;

        @Value("${spring.datasource.username}")
        private String dbUsername;

        @Value("${spring.datasource.password}")
        private String dbPassword;

        @Bean
        public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        }
        /// more code here 
}
```

SecurityConfig:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private OAuthUserDetailsService userService;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManager();
}

    // Hash password
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
       http
               .sessionManagement()
               .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
               .and()
               .httpBasic()
               .realmName("test")
               .and()
               .csrf()
               .disable();

    }
}
```

The UserRepository class is very simple:

```
    public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<OAuthUser, Long> {

    public OAuthUser findByUserName(String name);
}
```

How can I ensure all required beans are found for my tests?
Thanks.

EDIT:

I receive the same error if I attempt to @Autowire the bean in my test class.

```
@Autowired 
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `@DataJpaTest` this annotation should be used only for Data repositories test and not full integration (which is what you are doing) as because it only persistence beans are created in context and not all you beans (the reason bean can not be found). What you need to do is use only `@SpringBootTest` and declared `h2` as testing dependency, in that way a full recreation of your application will be created using in memory database

Comment: Thanks much for the response. However, this raises another question. How do I indicate that I wish to use h2 (which I do have on my classpath) and not my production database of choice (PostgreSQL)? I specified testCompile() for h2 in my build.gradle file and compile() for PostgreSQL, but the test still seems to be using PostgreSQL. Is there a way to override this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: connection string in application.properties/yml you can add updated version under test resources folder.